# Include zero in min COUNT with GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

in my query output cout without zero "greater than zero " how I can display zero count ?

```
SELECT MIN(Q)Z 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`Student_ID`)Q 
      FROM Examdata 
      WHERE `Student_ID` in (SELECT `Student_ID` FROM sal3 ) 
             and `Subject_ID`!='104 سلم' 
      group by exam_dates
     ) TABLE1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to look at every possible value of `exam_dates`, and the count the number of distinct values of Student_ID for each `exam_dates` that have a `Student_ID` and `Subject_ID` that satisfy the conditions...

we can relocate the conditional tests into the aggregation

For example:

```
SELECT MIN(t.q) AS Z
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
                      CASE
                      WHEN d.Student_ID IN ( SELECT s.Student_ID FROM sal3 s ) 
                       AND d.Subject_ID != '104 سلم' 
                      THEN d.Student_ID
                      ELSE NULL
                      END
                ) AS q 
           FROM Examdata d
          GROUP
             BY d.exam_dates
       ) t
```

---

The specification is very vague, without example data and expected output to illustrate the requirement, we're just guessing what should be returned.

The query in this answer does have potential to return a zero, when there is a row in `Examdata` with an `exam_dates` value for which no rows with that `exam_dates` value satisfies the conditions.

Comment: To me the whole question is problematic. The result will be 0 whenever there exists any row where the student is not in the sal3 table or the subject is not the desired Subject_ID. or am I missing something? If you're returning **ELSE NULL**, then you need **SELECT IFNULL(MIN(t.q), 0) AS Z**.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson: the **COUNT** aggregate will return a non-negative integer, not a NULL.The NULL from ELSE NULL will be returned to COUNT. And null values will get counted as zero. We know **t.q** will never be null. It won't change the result any if wrap **MIN(t.q)** in an **IFNULL**. The GROUP BY collapses rows by **exam_dates**. The return from COUNT will be greater than zero for a given **exam_dates** if there are any rows with that **exam_dates** val that match the conditions on Student_ID and Subject_ID. It doesn't matter if there are also rows that do not match the conditions.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson: even with an empty (no rows in) table **Examdata**, the query would return 0. What is problematic is the specification. The query in this answer satisfies one particular interpretation of several possible interpretations. It's likely that this query does not satisfy the actual requirements, which the question does not describe very well.

Comment: You’re absolutely correct. You were only returning NULL as an id to be counted and not as the count itself.